# Analytics / Conversion tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, analytics, conversion

Has anyone been able to make this script work?

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/collect_code/install_collect_code/track_conversion/

My understanding is it should work with the collect code

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/collect_code/install_collect_code/

Collect code tracks impressions but conversion tracking DOES NOT WORK for us when pasted on the purchase confirmation page.

Comment: Can you post your collection code?  Including the base collection script for `collect.js`?

Comment: Any JS errors in the browser console when the page loads?

Comment: collect code seems to work fine:
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://7220084.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "7220084"]); _etmc.push(["trackPageView"]); </script>

Comment: I don't see any JS errors Adam

collect code is on the landing page

after user goes through sign up and lands on the confirmation page, that's where the 'conversion code' resides 

that's what doesn't fire

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to get the conversion tracking to work with a simple test I landing page configured:

```
<h4>test tracking script</h4>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://<!-- MID GOES HERE -->.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js"></script> 
<h4>test tracking pageview</h4>
<script type="text/javascript">
  _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "<!-- MID GOES HERE -->"]);
  _etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);
</script>       
<h4>test conversion script</h4>       
<script type="text/javascript">       
  _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "<!-- MID GOES HERE -->"]);       
  _etmc.push(["trackConversion", { "cart": [
     {"item" : "ITEM1", "quantity":  "1" , "price" : "1.00" , "unique_id" : "ITEM1" } ,
     {"item" : "ITEM2", "quantity":  "1" , "price" : "1.23" , "unique_id" : "ITEM2" }],
  // OPTIONAL PARAMETERS
  "order_number" : "1234567890",
  "discount" : "0.50",
  "shipping" : "2.34",
  "details" : { "AttributeName" : "Value" }
  // END OPTIONAL PARAMETERS       
  }]);      
</script>
```

**Result**

[image: dashboard conversion]

Comment: Could it be that you pasted it on the same page?

But in real time situations - would you not put them on a separate pages?  Otherwise you'll get as many impressions as conversions.

Comment: It's up to you where you put the scripts.  My point was to illustrate that the conversion tracking script does record data. The `collect.js` will need to exist on all of the pages that have any tracking code.

Comment: hmm, could it be that collect.js needs to be together with conversion tracking

we'll try and update here

thank you Adam

Comment: That's probably the issue.

Comment: Anyone figured out how to set the Value column? Right now it seems my price is the sum of all items, but my Value is 0.